# React-Redux: Make api call after set state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a page in which I recover information about some managers. When the user choose one manager using a `<select>` I save the id in a state. Now I would to use this id to do another fetch from another api.

My problem is that at the beginning the manager state is undefined so the second api call give me a 500 errors until the manager id is set. Once the manager is chosen, the call to the API is made continuously (because it is inserted in the render).

I would find a method to do the second api call only one time after that the manager's id is choosen, how can I do in your opinion?

```
componentDidMount() {
// with this part I recover the managers' list
        this.props.managerList()
    }
//...
render() {
// this is the part:
         let managers = this.props.managers
         console.log("manager: ", managers)
         let idManager = this.state.manager_id; 
         console.log("idManager: ", idManager)
         if(typeof idManager != "undefined"){
          this.props.agendaList(idManager)
         }

        return (
      <div className = "ml-5 mr-5 mt-5">
          <div>
          </div>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
         <div>
          <label>Manager</label>
          <div className="bootstrap-select-wrapper">
// there I save the manager_id that I pass in my second api (agendaList)
            <select title="Choose Option" onChange={(e) => this.setState({ manager_id: e.target.value })}>
            <option value="" title="Choose Option" data-content="Cancel <span class='reset-label'></span>"></option>
            {managers && managers.length && managers.map((manager) => (
              <option key={manager.id}  value= {manager.id}  name="manager_id" >{manager.name} {manager.surname}</option>
            ))}
            </select>
            </div>
          </div>
```

EDIT. Ok I have edited the code thanks to your answer. The problem is now when I select the manager and do the agendaList(manager_id) call I obtain:

> Before I choose manager:

(2) [{…}, {…}]

```
0: {id: "12", name: "Name1", surname: "Surname1"}
1: {id: "13", name: "Name2", surname: "Surname2"
```

> After (so after I call this.props.agendaList(manager_id)

```
0: {id: "12", name: "Name1", surname: "Surname1"}
1: {id: "13", name: "Name2", surname: "Surname2"}
2: {manager_id: "12", date: "2020-05-27", start_at: "09:00:00"}
3: {manager_id: "12", date: "2020-05-27", start_at: "10:00:00"}
```

And I change the manager

```
(5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {id: "12", name: "Name1", surname: "Surname1"}
1: {id: "13", name: "Name2", surname: "Surname2"}
2: {manager_id: "12", date: "2020-05-27", start_at: "09:00:00"}
3: {manager_id: "12", date: "2020-05-27", start_at: "10:00:00"}
4: {manager_id: "13", date: "2020-05-28", start_at: "10:00:00"}
```

I would to separate the answer from my api.

```
case 'MANAGER_LIST':
            return [...state, ...action.managers];
        case 'AGENDA_LIST':
            return [...state, ...action.agenda];
```

Comment: What happens with the data from agendaList?

Comment: the data form agendList are an array that are saved in the state

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not make any API call inside render method. You can write a separate handler that sets the state and makes the API call

```js
handleChange = (e) => {
   const manager_id = e.target.value
   this.setState({ manager_id })
   this.props.agendaList(manager_id)
}
render() {
   let managers = this.props.managers
   console.log("manager: ", managers)
   let idManager = this.state.manager_id; 
   console.log("idManager: ", idManager)
   return (
      <div className = "ml-5 mr-5 mt-5">
         {/* Other code */>}
            <select title="Choose Option" onChange={this.handleChange}>
                <option value="" title="Choose Option" data-content="Cancel <span class='reset-label'></span>"></option>
                {managers && managers.length && managers.map((manager) => (
                  <option key={manager.id}  value= {manager.id}  name="manager_id" >{manager.name} {manager.surname}</option>
                ))}
            </select>
           {/*other code*/}
      </div>
   )
}
```

EDIT: As per your edited post it seems like you want the data to be separate. To do that you need to store them separately in reducers

```
const reducer = (state = {managers: [], agents: []}, action) => {
     case 'MANAGER_LIST':
            return {...state, managers: [...state.managers, ...action.managers]};
        case 'AGENDA_LIST':
            return {...state, managers: [...state.managers, ...action.agenda]};
}
```

post that you need to update your mapStateToProps too

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
   return {
      managers: state.managers,
      agenda: state.agenda,
   }
}
```

Comment: I think that the manager.id is not taken using ` this.handleClick `. I have tried your method but it seems that this.props.agendaList is not called

Comment: Have you written it as an arrow function?

Comment: I'm so stupid xD i didn't notice that the name was different

Comment: I notice one problem, the result of the second api call go directly in the same state of the managers, so they go also in the select :/

Comment: what do you mean by second API call?

Comment: in the componentDidMount i have ` this.props.managerList()` and this is the first api call, this.props.agendaList(manager_id) is the second

Comment: When you say `the result of the second api call go directly in the same state of the managers, so they go also in the select :/ ` What do you want to do exactly. Render both agentList and managers within the same select options?

Comment: So you need to separate the data

Comment: Yes because In the <select> are show blank field after the api call

Comment: Updating my answer

Comment: You need to update your reducers to store an object and not array, And update it like I showed in my post

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the second api call in an if state to only execute when manager state is not undefined. And your onChange should rather link to a function outside render, not important but good practice.

Answer (score 1):

Don't set the selected ID in state. On select, you can directly call redux action. 
For example,

This will call be called on manager drop down select,

```
onMangerSelect(selectedId) {
    this.props.getManagerDetails(selectedId);
}
```

This wil call redux action,

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    getManagerDetails : (managerId) => {
      dispatch(getDataFromManagerAPI(managerId));
    } 
  };
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, React is about being.. reactive!
A good mindset when working with React would be to always react to changes.

In my opinion, its OK to change the state like you did when selecting a value from the  component (*although I'd write an handling function like the first answer suggested for the sake of a cleaner and better organized code).

What you need to do, is make sure there's a piece of code that knows how to react to that change -> in our case, making the API call. An example solution could be:

```
componentDidMount() {
// with this part I recover the managers' list
        this.props.managerList()
    }
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
        // Whenever the component updates we'll check what changed and react
        // accordingly
        this.handleNewManagerSelection(prevState);
    }
handleNewManagerSelection(prevState) {
        const { manager_id } = this.state;
        // This means we have a new manager id in our state so we need
        // to run our agendaList API call
        if (prevState.manager_id !== manager_id) {
                this.props.agendaList(manager_id);
            }
    }
render() {
// this is the part:
         let managers = this.props.managers
         console.log("manager: ", managers)
         let idManager = this.state.manager_id; 
         console.log("idManager: ", idManager)
         if(typeof idManager != "undefined"){
          this.props.agendaList(idManager)
         }

        return (
      <div className = "ml-5 mr-5 mt-5">
          <div>
          </div>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
         <div>
          <label>Manager</label>
          <div className="bootstrap-select-wrapper">
// there I save the manager_id that I pass in my second api (agendaList)
            <select title="Choose Option" onChange={(e) => this.setState({ manager_id: e.target.value })}>
            <option value="" title="Choose Option" data-content="Cancel <span class='reset-label'></span>"></option>
            {managers && managers.length && managers.map((manager) => (
              <option key={manager.id}  value= {manager.id}  name="manager_id" >{manager.name} {manager.surname}</option>
            ))}
            </select>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Comment: this will cause infinite re-render ```this.props.agendaList(idManager)```

Comment: As long as the API call doesn't change the manager_id (which it probably won't because that would make no sense) it won't. This is a good working practice :)

Comment: No it's not.You shouldn't call a function that changes state inside render. what I meant was that it will make infinite requests https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-chaum-y1znj?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: did you see the above demo?